# redirect url to separate hosting while retaining file structure

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I own theone.com and twosies.com. I have my hosting bundled with twosies.

I have my site located in twosies.com/theone/

and reach it by twosies.com/theone/home.php

I would like to reach the site through theone.com/home.php

How do I do this?
I've used htaccess before but only to simplify page queries and remove file extensions.

regards

-taylor

*fixed a typo

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `mod_rewrite` nor `php` for it, a simple [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) does this:

```
Redirect /service http://foo2.example.com/service
```

Check the link for full details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function Redirect($path){
          ?>
          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                window.location = "<?php echo $path; ?>";
          </script>
          <?php
          }
?>
```